Pycharm keeps saying there is an unmatched [ in an f-string, but it is matched
for a class I'm trying to write a python program.  One of the lines tries to use an f string to report the value of a key ('cost') inside of a dictionary ('espresso') that is inside another dictionary ('MENU').  Unfortunately I keep getting:
print(f'That drink costs {MENU["espresso"['cost']]}.')
                                           ^

SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '['
The line of code that is throwing this error is as follows:
print(f'That drink costs {MENU["espresso"['cost']]}.')

I'm using Pycharm with Python 3.9.
I thought I understood the basic issue here; pycharm/python is for some reason not built to understand that single and double quotes inside the curly braces of an f-string are not actually the end of the print statement, so it would end the print statement and see the rest of the line as a jumble of characters, and throw a syntax error about them.
However if that were the case, it should be seeing the ']' as unmatched, not the '[' that I expected it to think is inside the print quotes and thus not required to be matched.  But it objects to the bracket that should be seen as inside the single quotes and fine to print either way.
I also see that I am trying to use single quotes for the 'cost' key inside the single quotes of the print statement, but I have to use double quotes for the "espresso" key of the first dictionary.  I'm not aware of any third way to show that I am indicating a key of a dictionary.  Is it impossible to reference a value inside a nested dictionary in an f string?

PyCharm and Jetbrains know Python better than you do.   Your first thought should be to doubt yourself.

That access to the dictionary won't work, even outside f-strings. You are indexing into the string (!) "espresso" with the index "cost".
There are two problems with your code:

Just index into the outer dictionary, then index into the inner dictionary. Do not nest the square brackets.
Inside ", you can only use ' and vice-versa. (This changes with f-strings in Python 3.12)

MENU = dict()
MENU["espresso"] = dict()
MENU["espresso"]["cost"] = 17.50
print(MENU['espresso']['cost'])         # without f-string
print(f"{MENU['espresso']['cost']}")    # with f-string
print(f'{MENU["espresso"]["cost"]}')    # vice-versa f-string


Thank you!  Your solution worked.  As I mentioned, I was aware of the second problem, but didn't see any way around it, given that I thought the cost key had to be 'nested' inside the reference to the espresso key/dictionary, just as the espresso key/dictionary is nested inside the brackets that enclose the MENU dictionary.  I find the correct format very counterintuitive (it looks like we are referencing two values, espresso and cost, in the MENU dictionary).
Can I ask why you put an exclamation after the word string in your reply? Is it bad to use strings in key-value pairs?  I see it a lot

The exclamation mark indicates that you are trying to index into a dictionary, but that "espresso" (in quotation marks) is actually a string, not a dictionary as you thought. Because at that time, the dictionary was not yet taken out of MENU.

In Python 3.12 and later, the f-string is perfectly well-formed, and you'll get the expected TypeError from attempting 'espresso'['cost'].

@chepner: "I'm using Pycharm with Python 3.9.", says OP

This is a "feature" that has been fixed in Python 3.12.  Prior to 3.12, the parser would look for the matching closing single or double quote that matched the opening quote, and that would be your f string.  So in your case, Python would see f'That drink costs {MENU["espresso"[' as the f-string and be confused.
As of 3.12, (PEP 701), f-strings got a formal grammar, and it's possible to put expressions inside the {} that include the opening quote.  Unless you  can update to 3.12, you just have to work around this by ensuring that whatever's inside the {} doesn't use the same un-backslashed quotation mark as the opening quotation mark.
But even after 3.12, the code still won't do what you meant.  You'll get a different runtime error, since "expresso"['cost'] is treating a string as a dictionary.  Do you mean menu["expression"]['cost']?

But that would still not work, because "espresso"['cost'] is invalid, no matter what changes they make to f-strings.

Well, I was explaining his error message about this mismatched [.  But you're right, I'll add a little bit more.
